# Meteor.js: what object does {$set: {...} } get?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

There seems to be a problem with my Posts.update(); method.

```
    var postProperties = {
        url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
        title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
    }

    Posts.update(currentPostId, {$set: postProperties}, function(error){
        if (error) {
            // display the error to the user
            alert(error.reason);
        }
        else {
            Meteor.Router.to('postPage', currentPostId);
        }
    });
```

currentPostId probably isn't at fault since remove works just fine:

```
Posts.remove(currentPostId);
```

So the postProperties Object must be:

```
Object {url: "https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope", title: "Random Title"}
```

Posts have a url, a title and a message. I have a .deny() method for the message so I'm not updating that.

Any insight of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What are the values of `currentPostId` and `this.currentPostId`?

Comment: this.currentPostId is 'undefined' and currentPostId is in this case 'wHtYDGjRgbWMYnzMy'. So I don't understand why currentPostId fails while this.currentPostId doesn't.

Comment: `this.currentPostId` doesn't fail because there is no such record to update. Try using `Posts.update({_id:  currentPostId}, ....) `

Comment: I'm still getting an 'Internal server error'. Also, the post with _id = currentPostId definitely exist.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at my terminal and so there was a

```
Exception while invoking method '/posts/update' ReferenceError: alert is not defined
```

The problem was a forgotten alert(); in the Posts.deny(); method. From what I now alert isn't part of Javascript but of DOM(?). After removing the alert() everything worked as it should.

The alert() in the code above ( Posts.update(); ) works because it is located in a

```
Template.postEdit.events({...});
```

Hence, handling DOM events, where alert(); works just fine.